# QtQuickControls 2.0 with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I setup a virtualenv and installed pyqt5 (PyQt5-5.7-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl):

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 .
source bin/activate
pip install pyqt5
```

I created a basic.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 100
    color: "red"
}
```

and tried to load it in my python code with:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QUrl('basic.qml'))
    view.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

It fails with

```
file:///[...]/main.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Controls": Cannot load library /[virtualenv]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so: (libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5: Can't open shared object file: File or directory not found) 
     import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 
     ^

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I checked. This file it complains about actually doesn't exist. But how can I install it? Does PyQt5 support QtQuickControls2 at all?

If I switch the import in basic.qml from `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` to `import QtQuick.Controls 1.2`, it works. But I want to use the new controls.

Comment: Can you show us **exactly** how did you create the virtual environment? List the precise command you gave to install PyQt5 etc so that we can check whether what you did is correct.

Comment: thanks. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in PyQt5. The package is missing both `libQt5QuickTemplates2.so` and `libQt5QuickControls2.so`.

Hoping that the Qt 5.7 build contained by the PyQt 5.7 package and the official Qt 5.7 build available at qt.io are built in a fully binary compatible way, one possibility could be to download and install Qt 5.7 from qt.io, and copy the missing libraries into your virtualenv. For example:

```
$ cp ~/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.* path/to/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib
$ cp ~/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5QuickControls2.* path/to/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib
```

Comment: I couldn't find any bug tracker, so I posted the issue on the PyQt mailing list: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-September/038043.html

Comment: Should be fixed in the next release: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-September/038044.html